# Counting TCP retransmissions

Tags: linux, unit-testing, networking, tcp

I would like to know if there is a way to count the number of TCP retransmissions that occurred in a flow, in LINUX. Either on the client side or the server side.

Comment: Are you running a server of some kind or is this for a personal machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see TCP retransmissions for a single TCP flow using Wireshark. The "follow TCP stream" filter will allow you to see a single TCP stream. And the `tcp.analysis.retransmission` one will show retransmissions.

For more details, this serverfault question may be useful: https://serverfault.com/questions/318909/how-passively-monitor-for-tcp-packet-loss-linux

Answer (score 11):

Looks like `netstat -s` solves my purpose.

Comment: It does, as long as you're okay with getting the number of TCP retransmissions for the whole computer as opposed to a given TCP connection.

Comment: Also, this counter will wrap/overflow eventually - the speed depends on the amount of issues and traffic.

Answer (score 1):

The Linux kernel provides an interface through the pseudo-filesystem `proc` for counters to track the `TCPSynRetrans`

For example:

```
awk '$1 ~ "Tcp:" { print $13 }' /proc/net/snmp
```

Per documentation:

```
* TCPSynRetrans

This counter is explained by `kernel commit f19c29e3e391`_, I pasted the
explanation below::
--
  TCPSynRetrans: number of SYN and SYN/ACK retransmits to break down
  retransmissions into SYN, fast-retransmits, timeout retransmits, etc.
```

You can also adjust these settings also through the pseudo-filesystem `procfs` but under the `sys` directory.  There is a handy utility that does this short-hand for you.

```
sysctl -a | grep retrans

net.ipv4.neigh.default.retrans_time_ms = 1000
net.ipv4.neigh.docker0.retrans_time_ms = 1000
net.ipv4.neigh.enp1s0.retrans_time_ms = 1000
net.ipv4.neigh.lo.retrans_time_ms = 1000
net.ipv4.neigh.wlp6s0.retrans_time_ms = 1000
net.ipv4.tcp_early_retrans = 3
net.ipv4.tcp_retrans_collapse = 1
net.ipv6.neigh.default.retrans_time_ms = 1000
net.ipv6.neigh.docker0.retrans_time_ms = 1000
net.ipv6.neigh.enp1s0.retrans_time_ms = 1000
net.ipv6.neigh.lo.retrans_time_ms = 1000
net.ipv6.neigh.wlp6s0.retrans_time_ms = 1000
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_max_retrans = 3
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_max_retrans = 300
```